# Populate submenu when NSMenu/NSMenuItem are moused over?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenu

On MacOS, I have a submenu with dynamic contents that would be expensive to constantly rebuild.  It would be great if when the user moves the mouse over the parent item -- before the submenu is actually displayed -- I could dynamically build the submenu's contents (NSMenuItems).

A SIMPLIFIED hierarchy of my menus is thus:

```
Application File Edit View Tools Window Help
```

The menu containing my submenu is in Tools:

```
Tools
   Foo 1
   Foo 2
   Foo 3 > (leads to submenu)
```

The submenu contains spellcheck suggestions.

As a reminder, Interface Builder creates the menu as such:

```
Tools (NSMenuItem)
     NSMenu
       Foo 1 (NSMenuItem)
       Foo 2 (NSMenuItem)
       Foo 3 > (NSMenuItem)
            NSMenu
                 First spellcheck choice (NSMenuItem)
                 Second spellcheck choice (NSMenuItem)
                 Third spellcheck choice (NSMenuItem)
```

My hope was to only rebuild the Foo 3 submenu when the user passed the mouse OVER Foo 3.  Has anyone successfully addressed this problem?

EDIT:  After testing suggestions, NSMenuDelegate methods will NOT be called for the submenu's NSMenu located beneath Foo 3.  This has led me to determine the best solution is to use the menu validation method for F00 3, which is (unfortunately) invoked any time the Tools menu is selected from the menu bar.

NOTE TO SO ADMINS: Why, in the world, would this question be marked to "close"?  It is a perfectly legitimate question, asked in a manner that most macOS engineers would easily understand.  Why is SO generally more unfriendly to legitimate questions than in the past few years?

Comment: "I have a submenu with dynamic contents..."  Where!?  Under what class!?

Comment: Have you tried `menuWillOpen:`? Or the Handling Tracking methods `numberOfItemsInMenu:` "Invoked when a menu is about to be displayed at the start of a tracking session so the delegate can specify the number of items in the menu." and `menuNeedsUpdate:` "Invoked when a menu is about to be displayed at the start of a tracking session."?

Comment: @Willeke - The documentation on "menuWillOpen" explicitly states: "Don’t modify the structure of the menu or the menu items during this method."  HOWEVER -- you might be correct about "menuNeedsUpdate" -- I'll see if I can receive that delegate method.  I'm not sure why "numberOfItemsInMenu" would be a desirable operation, but I'll test that too...

Comment: @ElTomato -- The submenu is comes off my NSMenuItem "Correct Current Word", which is a menu in my Tools menu (which is in the menu bar).  Because that submenu contains corrected spelling choices, it needs to be built contextually, depending on what word contains the insertion caret in the text.  That's what I meant by "dynamic contents".

Comment: @Willeke After testing extensively, it seems that menuNeedsUpdate and numberOfItemsInMenu are NOT called for the NSMenu* that sits between the NSMenuItem that has the submenu and its NSMenuItems.  It WILL be called for the parent NSMenu, in my case meaning the "Tools" menu in the menubar.  So with those choices, I might as well do my work when menu validation is called for each of the menu items in "Tools", populating the submenu when my item with the submenu is validated.  Said differently, there does not appear to be a way to invoke those methods when a submenu is moused over.

Comment: It sounds like the delegate of the "Tools" is set instead of the "Correct Current Word" menu. What do you mean by "moused over", when the submenu will pop up?

Comment: @Willeke -- I've carefully checked and I was explicitly setting the delegate for the NSMenu* that is beneath Foo 3/Correct Current Word (see my revised question, above), and NOT for the NSMenu* beneath Tools.  I DID TEST to see what happens if I did indeed set it to the Tool's NSMenu*, just to make sure the delegate methods functioned at all.  By moused over, I mean the Tools menu is opened, and the mouse moves over Foo 3 / Correct Current Word, highlighting that menu item.  Selecting the Foo 3/Correct Current Word menu item opens its submenu.

Comment: In my test app `menuNeedsUpdate:` is called (on macOS 10.15).